# Does getting a soft ban make it harder to catch Pokemon after?

Tags: pokemon-go

Okay so here's the story. I wrote a bot for Pokemon Go. I know it's against the terms of service, I just wanted to see if I could do it, I used it once fully expecting to get banned and got soft banned, deleted the source codes and everything, haven't used it since. Long story short, I went to New York, went to one pokestop and shut off the bot, got soft banned on my next login.

However this was a few days ago and my soft ban is up, but it's making it extremely hard to catch Pokemon, I probably deserve this yes, but my question is, does getting a soft ban make it harder to catch Pokemon afterwards?

---

***EDIT***

To test this theory I created another bot and sent myself to California and then to Oklahoma. I got soft banned again for 4 hours. I then went and started catching Pokemon *I HAVE NOT UPDATED YET*. So as far as I can see there's no real difference between the catching.

Comment: Probably not, but it gets harder to catch low level Pokémon with increasing trainer level.

Comment: @dly well here's what I've discovered I can catch Pidgey, Ratatas no problem. A Lickintounge (or however it's spelt) showed up today and I used an ultra ball to try to catch it, it broke out and ran away, this was after two attempts with a pokeball

Comment: @13aal I think one case with a lickitung is not a large enough sample size to form a conclusion.

Comment: @Pyritie I'll give you another example, I tried to catch a caterpie with a great ball about ten seconds ago, 10cp, broke out and ran away.

Comment: @13aal I lost multiple 10 CP Caterpie and other easy prey this way without any soft ban on my account to date.

Comment: You may still be softbanned, it's hard to tell if you are free of it or not.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'd agree if I couldn't catch Pokemon. I still can though

Comment: @dly So what do you think it has to do with the glitch they've been working on lately?

Comment: Don't know if the soft ban coincides with recent releases, but there have been [articles, such as this one](http://kotaku.com/pokemon-go-pisses-players-off-yet-again-by-making-pokem-1784773116) about a glitch Niantic acknowledged that made Pokemon harder to catch.

Comment: @king14nyr That's what I was just talking about

Comment: You also stop getting exp while softbanned I think, so if you are still getting exp then probably not.

Comment: did you make sure you disables the setting to allow mock locations? maybe this is why you are having the repeat bans....as to the pokemon running away on you this is a major frustration caused by recent updates....ive never been banned and have apx 1/10 of encounters break free and run...and just like the nintendo versions I have had repeat fails on great balls only to succeed with a standard pokeball....there just seems to be no way to adequately calculate on a random number generation on which chances are going to work just thank the devs for stealing their own code from ingress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been no evidence of this. Since this would be server side the only evidence we would have is checking the chances before and after like you have already done.